# Why doesn't a key path of bounds.origin.x work with CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I've got this working just fine by using `bounds.size.width` or `bounds.size.height` but nothing happens when using `bounds.origin.x` or `bounds.origin.y`

The values array is `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:]` as works with width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this just isn't animatable. I discovered that animating `position.x` or `position.y` was the way to go.

Comment: Also, changing bounds.origin doesn't make sense. Bounds is within the context of the view itself. Frame was probably what you were looking for. But... frame.origin is also not animatable I think.

Comment: Yes Frame would normally be what would make sense to change in this situation but Apple specifically say that it isn't animatable and Bounds is.

Comment: bounds.origin.x is an animatable property, and does work correctly.

However many layers will not show any visual differences after bounds.origin has been changed, e.g. the layer's contents will always be positioned within the bounds rect, so the origin has no effect in that case. OTOH, changing bounds.origin will move the sublayers of the layer around, as they are positioned relative to the layer’s coordinate space.